# Can't play midi file, Gstreamer keeps asking for i386 plugin that can't be installed (64bit)

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, package-management, gstreamer, midi

[image: It asks to install plugin, while the Install button is unclickable.]

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. When trying to play midi (.mid) file, it asks for a gstreamer plugin, but the Install button itself is unclickable.
Actually, I have `gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad` (GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack -- without the (i386) at the end) installed already.

How do we solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue still exists in Ubuntu 13.04 (64 bits). I can play midi with vlc (fluid-synth) and timidity but cannot with Totem/audacitous which keeps telling me to look for audio/midi decoder and cannot find them. I tried all kinds of wildmidi/fluidsynth/gstream-bad/timidity solution I could think about.

My ultimate goal would be to play midi files in chrome/firefox but it does not work. Too bad to see midi more and more unsupported while WebMIDI is starting to point out in HTML5